# What is performance strategy in angular service worker?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

Does angular service worker's dataGroups **performance** strategy is serving content from cache and then network OR is it serving from cache only?

I mean, is it cache and update strategy OR cache only strategy?

Answer (score 0):

It's a cache and update strategy.

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config

With the param `maxAge` you define how long they should be cached. Additionally you can also define a `strategy`, see the docs.